# Use named registration in autofac with MVC Filter Attribute Property Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autofac, action-filter

I'm using Autofac to fill in public properties of my filters, according to https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Mvc3Integration#Filter_Attribute_Property_Injection and it worked great.

Until I tried to use a named registration for one of the dependencies. I cannot find a way to do it. I tried to manually register my filters like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyCustomAttribute>()
       .WithProperty(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<INamedDependency>("dependencyName"));
```

before calling the RegisterFilterProvider method, but that didn't work.

Any ideas? In case this has been fixed in a newer version, I'm using version 2.5.2.830.

Thanks,
Kostas

Answer (score 0):

May be you just forgot to register INamedDependency instance in your container:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : FilterAttribute
{
    public IDependencyName DependencyName { get; set; }
}

public interface IDependencyName
{

}

public class DependencyName : IDependencyName
{

}

[Test]
public void ResolveCustomTest()
{
    // Arrange 
    var dependencyInstance = new DependencyName();
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterInstance(dependencyInstance).Named<IDependencyName>("dependencyName");
    builder.RegisterType<MyCustomAttribute>().WithProperty(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IDependencyName>("dependencyName"));
    builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
    var root = builder.Build();

    // Act
    var attr = root.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest").Resolve<MyCustomAttribute>();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(attr.DependencyName, dependencyInstance);
}
```